# Recursively Algorithm for the NIm game

Tags: python, algorithm

I am trying to solve the Nim game. There are two players and a stack of sticks. Players can pick 1, 2 or 3 sticks on their turn. Player to pick the last stick will loose.

I have a function that takes two parameter, number of sticks and boolean. If the boolean pamater is true, means player1 will start the game and if false, means player 2. The function returns True if player1 wins, and false if player1 loose.

```
def num_game(no_of_sticks, player_one):
    if player_one and no_of_sticks == 1:
        return False
    elif no_of_sticks % 2 == 0:
        return True
    elif no_of_sticks % 4 == 0 or no_of_sticks % 4 == 1:
        return num_game(no_of_sticks - 3, not player_one)
    elif no_of_sticks % 4 == 2:
        return num_game(no_of_sticks - 1, not player_one)
    elif no_of_sticks % 4 == 3:
        return num_game(no_of_sticks - 2, not player_one)
```

So, for instance, when I call `num_game(6, True)`, it returns `True`, Although, it should return `False`, because when the function runs and player1 takes 3 sticks form the stack, player2 takes 2, leaving player1 with one and hence player1 should loose and the function should return `False`.

If I call `num_game(5, True)`, it returns `True` which is incorrect result, it should also return `False`.

I am not able to accuratly pin point where/what I am doing wrong here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You haven't explained what the problem is.  If you're getting an unexpected result from the code, you have to give us _details_.  How did you call the function, what result did you expect, and what result did you get instead?

Comment: Sorry. I added more detail.

Comment: The straightforward solution is to test all of sticks-1, sticks-2, and sticks-3 to see if any win. You’ve implemented another algorithm to do only one check based on the remainder mod 4. You haven’t explained anything about your formula or why you expect it to be correct, so it’s impossible to tell whether your code follows a formula correctly.

Comment: Also, why are you expecting player_one to lose when there are 6 sticks? If they take 3 sticks then they’ll lose, but they aren’t forced to take 3 sticks.

Answer (score 1):

What happens specifically for calling `num_game(6, True)` is that `6 % 2 = 0` and therefore, the following condition will hold:

```
elif no_of_sticks % 2 == 0:
        return True
```

And you get an answer of `True`.

My question is What exactly are you trying to achieve, because `num_game(6, True)` can have multiple paths dependents on what the two players are doing (this is very much similar to an  [adversarial problem solving][1] as many 2-player games are). For example:

1. player 1 draws 3 (3 remain), player 2 draws 2(1 remain), player 1 draws 1 and loses
2. player 1 draws 1(5 remain), player 2 draws 3(2 remain), player 1 draws 1(1remain), player 2 draws 1 and loses.

There are of course many different paths which can be taken and either one of the payers can win or lose.

### Naïve solution Suggestion

If what you are trying to do is to see that if the beginning player plays ideally, will he win or lose regardless of the opponent's actions, perhaps this will work:

```
def num_game(no_of_sticks, player_one):
    if no_of_sticks == 1: return not player_one
    elif no_of_sticks == 2: return player_one  # drawing 1 will leave the oppenent with 1, forcing lose
    elif no_of_sticks == 3: return player_one  # drawing 2 will leave the opponent with 1 forcing lose
    else:  # number of stickes bigger than 3
        outcome1 = num_game(no_of_sticks-1, not player_one)
        outcome2 = num_game(no_of_sticks-2, not player_one)
        outcome3 = num_game(no_of_sticks-3, not player_one)
        # check if there is a way to win
        if player_one:
            return any([outcome1, outcome2, outcome3])
        else:
            return all([outcome1, outcome2, outcome3])
```

### Explanation

In the recursion you have three stopping conditions, when the sticks are either 1, 2 or three, with obvious ways to decide who wins. In case the number of sticks is bigger than 3, you compute recursively the winning person if you pick either 1 2 or three sticks.

1. If this is `player_one` turn, meaning we want `player_one` to win and therefore we will return `True` if any of the three probabilities yield `True` which means that player one wins.
2. If this is `player_two` turn, meaning we want `player_two` to win and we will return `True` only if all three possible choices will result in `player_one` wins.

When calling `num_game(6, True)`, the smart action for `player_one` will be to pick 1 stick, with 5 remaining sticks, `player_two` turn will result in either 4,3 or 2 sticks when `player_one` will play again, which means that `player_one` will win, and the function should return `True`.

### Better solution suggestion

This code however can be made to run much faster for large initial number of sticks if we will create a dictionary saving the results of previous computations. This will result in dropping the number of recursions being done which will make the code run faster.

**Example** - for 20 sticks we need to compute the result for 19,18 and 17 sticks. By computing the result for 19 we already computed the result for 18 and 17 and we would not need to run all those recursions again.
The implementation of this is need below:

```
def num_game_fast(no_of_sticks, player_one, memory=None):
    # The memory states weather the beginning player wins or the other player wins when having this number of sticks
    if memory is None:
        memory = {}
    if no_of_sticks == 1: return not player_one
    elif no_of_sticks == 2: return player_one  # drawing 1 will leave the opponent with 1, forcing lose
    elif no_of_sticks == 3: return player_one  # drawing 2 will leave the opponent with 1 forcing lose
    elif no_of_sticks in memory:  # if 'no_of_sticks` in memory, return solution from memory
        return memory[no_of_sticks] if player_one else not memory[no_of_sticks]
    else:  # number of stickes bigger than 3 and 'no_of_sticks` not in memory, computing and adding to memory 
        if no_of_sticks-1 not in memory:  # if 'no_of_sticks-1' is not in memory, compute and add to memory for future use
            outcome1 = num_game(no_of_sticks-1, not player_one)
            memory[no_of_sticks-1] = outcome1 if player_one else not outcome1
        else:  # take the result from memory
            outcome1 = (memory[no_of_sticks-1] if player_one else not memory[no_of_sticks-1])
        if no_of_sticks-2 not in memory:  # if 'no_of_sticks-2' is not in memory, compute and add to memory for future use
            outcome2 = num_game(no_of_sticks-2, not player_one)
            memory[no_of_sticks-2] = outcome2 if player_one else not outcome2
        else:  # take the result from memory
            outcome2 = (memory[no_of_sticks-2] if player_one else not memory[no_of_sticks-2])
        if no_of_sticks-3 not in memory:  #if 'no_of_sticks-3' is not in memory, compute and add to memory for future use
            outcome3 = num_game(no_of_sticks-3, not player_one)
            memory[no_of_sticks-3] = outcome3 if player_one else not outcome3
        else:  # take the result from memory
            outcome3 = (memory[no_of_sticks-1] if player_one else not memory[no_of_sticks-1])
        # check if there is a way to win and add it to the memory
        if player_one:
            memory[no_of_sticks] = any([outcome1, outcome2, outcome3])
            return any([outcome1, outcome2, outcome3])
        else:
            memory[no_of_sticks] = not all([outcome1, outcome2, outcome3])
            return all([outcome1, outcome2, outcome3])
```

### Timing

When running timing on both functions with 20 sticks, we get:

```
%timeit num_game(20, True)
10.5 ms ± 1.59 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
%timeit num_game_fast(20, True)
188 ns ± 12.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

For 30 sticks we get:

```
%timeit num_game(30, True)
4.81 s ± 192 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit num_game_fast(30, True)
757 ns ± 510 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

We can see that the number of recursions grow exponentially, making a long runtime if we are not using the memory of previous computations.

[1]: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/036402139290019Q#:~:text=In%20adversarial%20problem%20solving%20(APS,opponent's%20model%20of%20the%20agent.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is your problem:

```
if player_one and no_of_sticks == 1:
    return False
```

This statement is true if there is one stick left AND it is player one's turn.

But what if there is one stick left and it is player two's turn?

Comment: I tried this but it still returns True. If it's player1 turn and 1 stick left, then player1 lost, and the function should return False.

I editied the mistake I noticed  in the question.

Comment: num_game(5, False) should return True. Opponent picked 3 sticks first, I picked 1, leaving 1 for the opponent, hence he lost, and I won. So the function should be returning True.

Comment: @DreamB0yDani You still haven't fixed the problem.  If there is one stick left on player two's turn, then your code falls through to the case where it subtracts 3 from the sticks and calls itself again.